# unable to convert string to base64

Tags: asp.net, webcam.js

I am getting errors that "The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or an illegal character among the padding characters. "

```
 public Bitmap ConvertThis(string ImageText)
{
    Bitmap bitImage=null;
    if (ImageText.Length > 0)
    {
        Byte[] bitmapData = new Byte[ImageText.Length];
        bitmapData = Convert.FromBase64String(FixBase64ForImage(ImageText));

        System.IO.MemoryStream streamBitmap = new System.IO.MemoryStream(bitmapData);

         bitImage = new Bitmap((Bitmap)System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(streamBitmap));
    }
    return bitImage;
}
public string FixBase64ForImage(string Image)
{
    System.Text.StringBuilder sbText = new System.Text.StringBuilder(Image, Image.Length);

    sbText.Replace("\r\n", String.Empty);
    sbText.Replace(" ", String.Empty);

    return sbText.ToString();

}
```

> data:image/jpeg;base64,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

**
this is my string generated by webcam.js can any one please help me to fix the error.

Comment: Are you passing in the "data:image/jpeg;base64," part? Because that's not part of the Base64 encoded string.

Answer (score 0):

You have to strip out the `data:image/jpeg;base64,` at the beginning, as it is not part of the base-64 encoding.

```
public string FixBase64ForImage(string Image)
{
    System.Text.StringBuilder sbText = new System.Text.StringBuilder(Image, Image.Length);

    var header = "data:image/jpeg;base64,";
    sbText.Replace(header, String.Empty, 0, header.Length);

    return sbText.ToString();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take snapshot and get image data

```
document.getElementById('results').innerHTML =
'<img id="imageprev" src="' + data_uri + '"/>';

var base64image = document.getElementById("imageprev").src;
```

base64 format :

```
 var strImage = base64image.replace(/^data:image\/[a-z]+;base64,/, "");
```